# Problems in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT, and I have the following problem: I want to get the description and maximum date of the following elements,

Facebook 01/01/2020
WhatsApp 02/01/2020
Instagram 04/01/2020
Twitter 05/01/2020
YouTube 03/01/2020

```
<xsl:variable name="fechas" as="element()*">
    <Item><xsl:value-of select="20200101"/></Item>
    <Item><xsl:value-of select="20200102"/></Item>
    <Item><xsl:value-of select="20200104"/></Item>
    <Item><xsl:value-of select="20200105"/></Item>
    <Item><xsl:value-of select="20200103"/></Item>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="description" as="element()*">
    <Item><xsl:value-of select="Facebook"/></Item>
    <Item><xsl:value-of select="Whatsapp"/></Item>
    <Item><xsl:value-of select="Instagram"/></Item>
    <Item><xsl:value-of select="Twitter"/></Item>
    <Item><xsl:value-of select="YouTube"/></Item>
</xsl:variable>
```

The result I hope to get is:
Twitter 05/01/2020

Comment: Hello Cristy, Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get useful answers, please use the question title as a summary of the question you are asking, and please try to ask only _one_ question (I think you are trying to ask at least two questions in one post - "how to join two element lists pair-wise?" and "how to take the maximum from a list according to some ordering?"). Also, please specify the XSLT version you are using.

Comment: What if there's a tie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have shown us some data contained in XSLT variables, not in any XML source document. You haven't told us why the data is organized in this rather strange way. If I were handling this data, I would probably put it in an XML document of the form

```
<data>
  <item site="Facebook" date="2020-01-01"/>
  <item site="Whatsapp" date="2020-01-02"/>
  ...
</data>
```

Why is this better?

- Data held in an XML document is more reusable than data held as variables in your XSLT code
- It's always best to use ISO date formats rather than non-standard formats.
- Standard practice for converting an object data model into XML is that objects become elements and properties of the objects become attributes (or child elements).

If the data takes this form, and the document is accessed as

```
<xsl:variable name="data" select="document('data.xml')"/>
```

Then in XSLT 2.0+, one way of solving your problem is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$data//item">
  <xsl:sort select="xs:date(@date)"/>
  <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You're new to XSLT so you may not yet be aware that there are different versions of XSLT. Back in 2000, a great many vendors (including Microsoft, Sun, IBM, Oracle and quite a few open source vendors, as well as all the browser vendors) delivered implementations of the new XSLT 1.0 standard. Many of these have not been updated since. But the language has moved on, and XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 are much more powerful. You need to decide whether you want to take advantage of the power of the newer versions, or whether you want to write code that will still run on the maximum number of platforms. It's therefore important when you ask XSLT questions on StackOverflow about XSLT that you specify which version.

(I've just noticed you are using `xsl:variable/@as`, which implies XSLT 2.0 or later).

For example, this particular problem involves manipulation of dates, and date arithmetic is provided in XSLT 2.0, but can only be done "by hand" in XSLT 1.0.

If there really is a good reason for starting with the data in the form you have shown it in your question, it's probably best to start by transforming it into a more easily handled form. You can do that (again in XSLT 2.0) with code like this:

```
<data>
  <xsl:for-each select="1 to count($fechas)">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="."/>
    <item site="{$description[$i]}" date="{$fechas[$i]}"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</data>
```